# Screen slows down when GPU-Util is about 50%

Tags: gpu, nvidia, slowdown

Screen runs smoothly when GPU-Util is about 25%, but pretty slowly for 55%. In the first case GPU memory usage was around 5.7GB/8GB and the second one 5.2GB/8GB.

On a second GPU (which I'm pretty sure the OS is not using) I have GPU-Util 99%, which makes me think GPUs have the capability to reach very high GPU-Util if needed.

My hypothesis is there is nothing wrong with my computer, but that I'm missing something of how things work.

Why does the screen slow down at 55% and not in the 90s?

In case it helps, I'm on Linux14.04 with 2 GTX-1080 and I get GPU-Util running nvidia-smi.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being something dumb.

Even though the processes I was running were GPU intensive, RAM was even more strained.